# XmlSerializer encoding

Tags: java, xml, encoding

I need to put some data from HashMap into xml. But there is a problem with Windows-1251 encoding - it returns xml with tag like "&#1090*;&*#1088*;&#1080*;" etc. Here is the code with test hashMap with cp1251 values:

```
public String getValues() {
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("one", "один");
    map.put("two", "два");
    map.put("three", "три");

    try {
        serializer.setOutput(outputStream, "Windows-1251");
        serializer.startTag("", "fields");
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            serializer.startTag("", key);
            serializer.text(map.get(key));
            serializer.endTag("", key);
        }
        serializer.endTag("", "fields");
        serializer.endDocument();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString);
    }
    return outputStream.toString();
}
```

How can I correctly set encoding? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found solution (I used wrong encoding):

```
serializer.setOutput(outputStream, "UTF-8");
```

Now all works fine